# How to switch inputted text between 2 colored boxes in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

So far I only have the code that is able to make 2 boxes, made the 4 buttons, but only 1 button actually does something, and that is the start button where a there is a popup that asks for a name, and after you input that name, it will appear in the first box.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function myTask1() {
        var sentence = prompt("Please enter a name");
        var arrSentence = sentence.split(" ");
        if (arrSentence != null) {
          document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = arrSentence.sort(); //so we can use Array.sort() function 
        }
        console.log(sentence);
        return sentence;
      }

      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById()
      }

    </script>
    <style> </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p><button type="button" onclick="myTask1()">Click me!</button></p> 
    <button type="button" onclick="ClearFields();">Clear</button> 
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> --> </button> 
    <button type="button" onclick="myTask4()"><-- </button> 
      <div clas="box" style="background-color:red; height:200px; margin:20px auto;">
        <center>
          <p id="answer1"></p>
          <center>
        </div>
        <div class="box1" style="background-color:grey; height:200px; margin:20px auto;"> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: can you post the code you have so we can help you?

Comment: Can you please specify what you are using? Is this straight HTML? Please edit your question to put your current HTML code. Also, split your image so that it is more readable, leave text in text and not in the image, this makes it easier to search and find your answer.

Comment: I tried, but it says that the code isnt indented correctly with 4 spaces and what not.

Comment: sorry, but that is the only way it allowed me to enter the code

Comment: I've added the code to your question. For suture reference, select the text and hit the `{}` button to turn it into a code block.

Comment: Do you want users to only select and move one of the entered names, multiple or all of them? And if a new name is added, should it override the previous name or should be sorted with the existing data?

Comment: Only the one name that they have entered. 
After the user is asked for the name which is asked by the popup after clicking start, the name should appear in one box, and by clicking the arrows, you switch the name location from left to right and vice versa.
And by clicking clear, the name should disappear.

Comment: And yes, if a new name is added, it should override the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some demo code for you. I assume that you're a beginner because the question is basic. This is not a problem though, starting something new is great. You can find the answer on the internet and the best programmers are often people who are good with Google. But I hope by showing you the solution anyway you get a feeling for structure. Try to understand every line. Try write it from scratch afterwards anyway. It's a great exercise.

Code: https://github.com/Bunpasi/stackoverflow-answers/blob/master/js-listbox-selector/index.html

Some things to notice:
- I've put the script in the footer so it doesn't interfere with the loading time of the page.
- I've put all code in an anonymous function to avoid global functions.
- I changed `clas` to `class`.
- I've used event listeners instead of even attributes.
- I didn't duplicate the logic for both boxes but used one function which I can use on both.

After your understand the code, there are some things you can improve on this code.
- Make sure the selection doesn't go away after the update. You can store this in the data as well. Right now the data is an array of ID's, but you can turn it into an array of objects containing even more important data, like whether it's selected.
- Move the style from the elements to the header.

Don't be discouraged by down votes.

Good luck!

**Update**

If you want to move all names all the time. This is what you need to do.

This line looks for all selected elements:

```
var selectedElements = boxes[fromId].querySelectorAll('.list_item.selected');
```

Remove the `selected` .selector:

```
var selectedElements = boxes[fromId].querySelectorAll('.list_item');
```

Comment: Thank you. But I do not understand. When I run that code, it gives me the same result I got before.

Comment: @Ziad: you can now click on the names you've entered and use the move buttons on them.

Comment: hmmmm, I think something went wrong. It does not allow me to do that

Comment: The buttons dont work for me. Although when I click on the name, it turns a bit of the box green.

Comment: @Ziad What happens if you make a couple of names green and than click one of the move buttons.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you did. I am trying to make it so I can freely swap the name from box to box without clicking on the name first.

Comment: @Ziad I added an update. You can then of course remove the selection functionality.

Comment: @Ziad great to hear! Can you mark the question as answered? The check mark changes color once clicked.